# ShowWindow not displaying

Tags: windows, winapi

So, I am working on a project, and the first step I wanted to have done is to create a window, and I figured I would populate it later. I use createwindowex to make it:

```
IntPtr newWindow = CreateWindowEx(WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, "HelloWin", "New Window", WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 100, 100, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, hInstance,IntPtr.Zero);
```

And show it using ShowWindow:

```
ShowWindow(newWindow, ShowWindowCommands.Normal);
```

Is there anything I am forgetting to do between these 2 methods? I am not getting any errors and everything else I have set up is running, the window isn't popping up though. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a message loop running on the same thread that created the window?

Comment: Also, did you verify that the window is getting created correctly (and that newWindow is not NULL/0)? Can you see it in Spy++?

Comment: newWindow is 0, I will work on that now, I am not sure why it is happening, is it possible that the parent or menu need to not be 0?

Answer (score 1):

I think, that problem is, you dont call UpdateWindow after ShowWindow.
But I am not working in .Net, only pure win32 api. :-)

Comment: Even using the raw Win32 API with C, you shouldn't need to explicitly call `UpdateWindow` after calling `ShowWindow`.